# ES6 modules: why a previously exported module is not known by "child" modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to put together a module based architecture for my Meteor/Node application.

I have a `client/main.js` importing a `imports/module1/index.js`.

The `imports/module1/index.js` imports a `imports/module1/api/api.js` after it imports a component `imports/module1/component/component1.js`.

To sum it up, the simplified tree would look like this

```
.client/main.js
 |_imports/module1/index.js
     |_imports/module1/api/api.js
     |_imports/module1/component/component1.js
```

The `api.js` file looks like that:

```
export default {
  myFunction1 (arg1, arg2) {
    // function stuff
  },
  myFunction2 (arg1, arg2) {
    // function stuff
  },
}
```

I expected to be able to call `myFunction1(ar1,arg2)` inside the `imports/module1/component/component1.js` but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you import `api.js` in your `component1.js` file? Can you show how do you do that?

Comment: No I don't, I import both of them in `imports/module1/index.js` , I assumed it was already loaded.

Comment: Why would it be? Scope of a file doesn't "leak" so each file is completely separate in this matter. You have to import something in order to be able to use it.

Comment: You should not default-export such "namespace" objects. Rather have two named exports for the two functions.

Comment: If you don't mind, what is the reason behind our advice? What is the difference? I can still import my functions separately, like `import {myFunction1} from '../api/api.js'`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you don't import `api.js` in your `component1.js` file so component1 has no access to any functions defined in the api.

Scope of a file doesn't "leak" so each file is completely separate in this matter. `import` in the `main.js` file doesn't automatically make all the imported modules available to its child modules – this wouldn't make sense. You have to import something in order to be able to use it.